# Initialising a Subclass that extends an Abstract class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a TableModel class that extends the AbstrctTableModel class in java swing but when I try to initialise the subclass which is not abstract, the Netbeans 8.0 IDE complains that I am initialising an abstract class.
 the code snippets are provide below.

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private List<List<Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
 private String[] header = { "ID","SUBJECT","LETTTER FROM","LETTER DATE","DATE RECEIVED",
                              "REMARKS","DATE DISPATCHED","DESTINATION OFFICE"};
 private int minRowCount = 5;

public TableModel()
{  }

public List<List<Object>> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}

public void setDataList(List<List<Object>> dataList) {       
    this.dataList = dataList;
    fireTableDataChanged();       
    fireTableStructureChanged();        
}

public void setHeader(String[] header) {
    this.header = header;
}

public String[] getHeader() {
    return header;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return Math.max(minRowCount, dataList.size());
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return header.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col) {
return header[col];
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
    Object value = null;
    if(row < dataList.size())      
    {value = dataList.get(row).get(col);}
    return value;
}


 @Override
 public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {   
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }              
        }
        return Object.class;
    }
}
```

this is the code that initialises the Table Model class.

```
 private TableColumnAdjuster tca;

 /**
 * Creates new form MyJFrame
 */

 private TableModel tableModel ;

public MyJFrame() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException,
                               ParseException, java.text.ParseException, SQLException 
{

    tableModel = new TableModel(); // the Netbeans IDEcomplains about this code

    initComponents();


}
```

Comment: Check which `TableModel` you have imported.

Comment: thanks, it was rather a wrong importation that caused the problem. Was able to fix with the right impotation

Comment: As a side note, you should post the precise error message from NetBeans, as this gives a hint what goes wrong.

Comment: @CodeAngel class name `public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {` should be  `public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {`

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any info to specify the exact nature of the complaint, but I'm betting that the `AbstractTableModel` has an abstract method that your `TableModel` has failed to override.  It would be a compilation error in that case.

If that's true, provide a concrete implementation for that method and you'll be able to take the next step.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion , but it was rather a wrong importation of the table that caused the error. Was able to fix it.

Comment: [TableModel is reserved Java word:-)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)

Comment: Not true about TableModel being a reserved word.  It's true that javax.swing.table.TableModel is a class in the JDK.  You can have your own TableModel if it is in a different package.  You'll have to make sure that the code knows that you mean your package and not the one in the JDK.